# reinstalling sdl manually on buntu

Tags: sdl, ubuntu-10.04, reinstall

I am new to doing manually installing.

I reinstalled sdl manually, now everytime I run pygame or a game that uses SDL (eg. solarwolf or supertux) I get the message: Unsupported console hardware. 
I know my computer can run SDL, because it worked prior to the reinstallation.

I want to now how I can reinstall SDL properly, so that pygame will work again.

versions:
ubuntu: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx
sdl: 1.2.14

## Stuff I have tried:

1)
I have tried this commandoes I found on the net:
 wget http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz
 tar -xzvf SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz
 cd SDL-1.2.14
 ./configure --prefix=$HOME
 make
 make install

2)
I tried again with sudo and no prefix. Maybe that wrecked some prior configurationsfile or something?
 wget http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz
 tar -xzvf SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz
 cd SDL-1.2.14
./configure
make
sudo make install

3)I used the Synaptic Package Manager to completely remove and reinstall all files starting with libsdl.

4)I have tried reinstalling supertux and solarwolf (with ubuntu software senter)
hoping it could resolve the problem if there were some missing dependencies.

Conclusion. I geuss a have installed sdl, but wrecked a confirgurationfile or something preventing communication between sdl and the graphic driver.
But that is a wild guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds strange.
try: sudo ldconfig

from man ldconfig

"ldconfig  creates,  updates,  and removes the necessary links and cache
       (for use by the run-time linker,  ld.so)  to  the  most  recent  shared
       libraries  found  in  the directories specified on the command line, in
       the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/usr/lib  and
       /lib).   ldconfig  checks the header and file names of the libraries it
       encounters when determining which  versions  should  have  their  links
       updated.  ldconfig ignores symbolic links when scanning for libraries.
"